# Django Models How to

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

So I'm new to Django and I'm trying to develop a timecard. Employees need to allocate their time to a client's project whether billable or unbillable. They would have to log in, choose to which clients project they worked on, enter time worked and log out.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) guide to asking questions. For your problem, you should take some Django tutorials to learn the basics of Django models.

Comment: No problem :). I really hope you have good luck learning Django!